# Sonarqube throws error Remove this override of "isNaN"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube, lodash

I'm using react in one of my projects. Everything works fine except sonarqube is throwing multiple errors

Remove this override of "isNaN"
Remove this override of "toString"
Remove this override of "parseInt"

I'm using lodash library to perform the operations and importing it the following way

```
import isNaN from 'lodash/isNumber';
import toString from 'lodash/toString';
import parseInt from 'lodash/parseInt';
```

Functionality wise everything seems to work but can't get rid of these errors.
What am I doing wrong here.
I also checked lodash documentation but couldn't figure out the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you remove those statements, does your code run?

Comment: Yeah @Bravo it runs

Answer (score 0):

Because it has the same name with the default function.

Just rename it

```
import isNaNLodash from 'lodash/isNumber';
import toStringLodash from 'lodash/toString';
import parseIntLodash from 'lodash/parseInt';
```

Comment: I have replaced isNan one.
But I have found instance of toString in the code.
```
items: group.items.map(item => ({
      id: `${toString(group.groupId)}.${toString(item.id)}.${toString(item.value)}.${toString(item.comparisonType)}`,
      label: item.title,
    })),
```
Are you saying I should make it as `${toStringLodash(group.id)}` ?

Comment: Yes. Please rename all

Comment: if it runs without them ... why would you :p

Comment: @Bravo it runs but sonarqube still displays it as a bug

Comment: How can it be a bug if you don't import them ... seems like you may not be doing something right

Comment: @Bravo The bug is about overriding native function.